# Applying position: fixed, to elements inside of a position: absolute parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a div which functions as an overlay over the `body`, when the overlay is active, scrolling on the document body is disabled, but any overflow on the overlay is set to `overflow-y: scroll`.

```
.showComments {
  animation: show-comments 250ms forwards;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

`.showComments` is my parent container. Inside of it, I have a `nav` child, I would like to apply a `position: fixed` to my `nav`, so that it stays flush on the top of the page during any user scrolling. Is this possible to implement or are there any workarounds? Not sure if helpful but also added my CSS for the `nav`

**NAV**

```
.nav {
  border-bottom: $nav-border;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: $color-white;

  h3 {
    font-family: $font-primary;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  svg {
    font-size: $icon-size;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is as position: fixed (or sticky) seems to work - but maybe there is  more in your code which changes this. Could you put up a working snippet so we can see the relevant HTML structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the nav outside of the overlay and make it sibling as shown below. Set the parent to relative and position the two children elements with absolute or fixed as needed.

```css
.overlay-wrap{
  display: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: .7;
}
.nav{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height: 4rem;
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
li{
margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-wrap">
  <nav class="nav">
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>LOGIN</li>
  </nav>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```